# how to i use SET @variable to set values for variables in mysql for query in yii

Tags: mysql, yii, set

my query such as having mysql variable declaration

```
SET @var1=0, @var2=0;
```

these variables are used in the select query

which works fantastic in phpmyadmin
but then if i write it as query in yii doesnt work

throws exception doesnt not execute but then if i remove

```
SET @var1=0, @var2=0;
```

then query  executes but with no data fetched from db because it requires the set variables to fetch the result

how do i declare the set values of mysql in yii?is there any way out

Answer (score 1):

As long as you reuse the same CDbCommand, you can issue multiple queries to the DB using the same connection. That will do what you need (and is what phpMyAdmin does).

Your problem is that you're doing two queries on different connections to the DB and your @vars aren't lasting between connections.

Comment: ya exactly, i solved my issue using stored procedures :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have set statements, you're probably writing something that is a little more procedural than a single sql statement is designed to deliver.

I would look at write in a stored procedure to the the job (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569).   Although they are a bit old school - they will probably do what you want quite effectively.

Comment: ya exactly its more then asingle statment. I would prefer for procedures but haven't worked with it anytime can you please provide some guidance or demo avaible in yii.and thanx for the quick reply

Comment: i did it issue using stored procedures :) thank u for the info

Comment: Sorry about the delay in getting back to you - I've been in meetings all day.  Glad that it worked.

Comment: not a problem ,me too glad that I did it thanks for the guidance :).